# Are there quantum circuits or quantum algorithms that generate arbitrary discrete distributions?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit

Are there quantum circuits or quantum algorithms that generate arbitrary discrete distributions? such as a discrete normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Qiskit Finance contains quantum circuits for the following probability distributions:

- [Normal Distribution](https://qiskit.org/documentation/finance/stubs/qiskit_finance.circuit.library.NormalDistribution.html)
- [Log-Normal Distribution](https://qiskit.org/documentation/finance/stubs/qiskit_finance.circuit.library.LogNormalDistribution.html)
- [Uniform Distribution](https://qiskit.org/documentation/finance/stubs/qiskit_finance.circuit.library.UniformDistribution.html)